# How do i truncate array keys

Tags: php, arrays, truncate

Hey there, i am trying to generate a chart based on some array, but to assign the x labels, i need to truncate my keys to 5 characters or something...

so from :

```
Array ( [Fruits totals] => 61 [Vegetables totals] => 71)
```

to

```
Array ( [Fruit] => 61 [Veget] => 71)
```

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just iterate over the array:

```
$truncated = array();

foreach($array as $key => $val) {
    $truncated[substr($key, 0, 5)] = $val;
}
```

Note that two different entries in the original array could have the same truncated key. In this case the last entry will overwrite previous values.